# CSS Menu Under Flash Slideshow

Tags: css, flash, transparent

I've tried using wmode transparent codes on my SWF slideshow but the menus still seem to appear behind the Flash in IE8 and Firefox 3.5... In IE7 it works although the looks of the menus aren't as good.

Here's the Flash code:

```
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','524','height','313','title','LoveRugs','src','http://www.love-rugs.com/Slideshows/Love-Rugs-Slide','quality','high','loop','false','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','http://www.love-rugs.com/Slideshows/Love-Rugs-Slide' ); //end AC code
</script>
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="524" height="313" title="LoveRugs"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"/>
<param name="movie" value="http://www.love-rugs.com/Slideshows/Love-Rugs-Slide.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
</object>
<embed src="http://www.love-rugs.com/Slideshows/Love-Rugs-Slide.swf" wmode="transparent" quality="high" loop="false" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="524" height="313"></embed>
</noscript>
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the flash object in a DIV and give it a z-index that is lower than the item you want to be on top of it.